# Java - arrays - Flow control, looping and branching

Tags: java, arrays

In the code below you need to get a array of negative articles and a array of positive articles. How to get a arrays without zero.

```
package niz;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class Niz {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

        int array1[] = new int[array.length];
        int array2[] = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            if (array[i] < 0)
                array1[i] = array[i];
            else
                if (array[i] > 0)
                    array2[i] = array[i];

        HashSet<Integer> notDupes = new HashSet<>();
        HashSet<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if (!notDupes.contains(array[i]))
            {
                notDupes.add(array[i]);
                continue;
            }   
            duplicates.add(array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("negative members of the array: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(array1));
        System.out.println("positive members of the array : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(array2));
        System.out.println("number of duplicates : " + duplicates.size());

    }
}
```

The following is the output:

```
run:
negative members of the array: [0, 0, -22, 0, 0, 0, -4, -55, 0, 0, 0, -999, -87]
positive members of the array : [12, 23, 0, 0, 43, 545, 0, 0, 43, 12, 0, 0, 0]
number of duplicates : 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Hlo, user separate index-variable for -ve and +ve arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List` instead of arrays to leverage their power of shrinking, getting wider and smaller as long as you add new items and remove others.

Note that when you instantiate a new `array` Object, it will initialize all elements with default types, in you case the `int` items will be initialized to `0` thus you will have as much zeros as the array size.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class Niz
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

    List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      if (array[i] < 0)
        array1.add(array[i]);
      else
        array2.add(array[i]);

    HashSet<Integer> notDupes = new HashSet<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      if (!notDupes.contains(array[i]))
      {
        notDupes.add(array[i]);
        continue;
      }
      duplicates.add(array[i]);

    }

    System.out.println("negative members of the array: " + array1);
    System.out.println("positive members of the array : " + array2);
    System.out.println("number of duplicates : " + duplicates.size());

  }

}
```

As a side note, you should avoid unnecessary condition block, such as `else if` statement since when an int literal is negative (`if (array[i] < 0)`), then it will be positive for sure thus no need for the (`else if (array[i] < 0)`) check.

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize an array of integers, the default elements in the array are zero. Therefore, after filling these arrays, you will still have zero elements inside it corresponding to the numbers that you did not fill. To solve this you can use `List`s instead for which you don't have to initialize to a fixed size. If you still would like to have arrays at the end, you can convert the `List` to an array.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] < 0)
        list1.add(array[i]);
    else if (array[i] > 0)
        list2.add(array[i]);

Integer array1[] = list1.toArray(new Integer[list1.size()]);
Integer array2[] = list2.toArray(new Integer[list2.size()]);
```

By the way, it would not take much time at all to detect this with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

As a lazy person I would do following:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] numbers = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

    int[] positiveNumbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(n -> n > 0).toArray();
    int[] negativeNumbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(n -> n <= 0).toArray();
    int numOfDuplicates = numbers.length - (int)Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().count();

    System.out.println("negative members of the array: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(positiveNumbers));
    System.out.println("positive members of the array : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(negativeNumbers));
    System.out.println("number of duplicates : " + numOfDuplicates);
}
```

Comment: for this line  int numOfDuplicates = numbers.length - (int)Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().count(); I totally get what you did except why u subtract numbers.lenth from (int)Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().count()

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are not dynamically sized. When you create the two arrays (one negative, and one positive) but both the same size as the original array; you will get entries that are 0 (because that's the default initial value for an `int` in an array). Use two `List`(s),

```
List<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> al2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] < 0)
        al1.add(array[i]);
    else if (array[i] > 0)
        al2.add(array[i]);
```

Then to print the `List`(s),

```
System.out.println(al1);
System.out.println(al2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have maintain a counter while inserting data both for positive array and negative array. Otherwise your array will display 0 for places where you have not put data. This is because all the elements on an array of int will contain 0 by default. for eg

```
if(array[i] < 0)
array1[i] = array[i];
```

should be

```
if(array[i] < 0)
array1[negativeInde++] = array[i];
```

Also I am of the opinion that using primitive data types is more suited to your cause as using a wrapper like Integer will mean more overheads and incase you have a large array you will take too much time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this but you will still get zeros at the end as you have unwanted size.

```
    int ctr1 =0;
    int ctr2 =0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        if(array[i] < 0)
            array1[ctr1++] = array[i];

        else

        if(array[i] > 0)
            array2[ctr2++] = array[i];
```

To get rid of them as well. Use the following code.

```
int ctr1 = 0;
int ctr2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        ctr1++;
    } else if (array[i] > 0) {
        ctr2++;
    }
}
int array1[] = new int[ctr1];
int array2[] = new int[ctr2];
ctr1=ctr2=0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        array1[ctr1++] = array[i];
    } else if (array[i] > 0) {
        array2[ctr2++] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you an object-oriented approach, taking advance of the facilities of the Collections API. It is quite clearer:

Code an extension of ArrayList overriding the add() method, so that it only includes positive numbers. Code another extension for negatives.

Then, all you need is create four collections:

- A List to include the original array items.
- A positive ArrayList.
- A negative ArrayList.
- A Set for the not-duplicates.

... and just ONE loop, to iterate the original array adding an item to every collection.
After all, remove the not-duplicates from the original list through the removeAll method.